# Drawing a mixing zone with curved and squiggly lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

I am trying to create the following picture.
[image: mixingzone].

I have only gotten so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,3);
        \draw (0,0) -- (0,3);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=0mm}] (0,2.5) -- (0.9,2.5);
        \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=0mm}] (1.1,2.5) -- (2,2.5);
        \draw[dashed] (0.9,2.5) to[out=-180,in=180] (1,1.5);
        \draw[dashed] (1.1,2.5) to[out=0,in=0] (1,1.5);
        \draw[red] (0.9,3.2) -- +(0,-0.7);
        \draw[red] (1.1,3.2) -- +(0,-0.7);
        \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a) at (0.9,2.5) {};
        \vertex (b) at (1,1.5);
        \diagram{(a) -- [gluon] (b) -- };
        \end{feynman}
        \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: tikzoutput].

I can handle the text part but I am having a hard time figuring out the lines in the mixing zone. Also, is there a way around the straight line portion of the snake line. I want to have a continuous squiggly line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably much easier and quicker to draw this in a vector drawing program like Inkscape, instead of using tikz.

Answer (score 3):

The mixing probably is best done in something like Inkscape. Unless you want something like the following, which looks a bit on the hellish side of demonic to me.

However, the main point of this answer is to demonstrate one way to prevent the `snake` straightening out. Another would be to ensure that the `amplitude` divides exactly into the path length. Clipping a longer path to size is, in my opinion, a lot easier.

Here, we define a `pic` to do the clipping, draw the path and limit the effects to a local scope. The `pic` named `wiggle` takes 2 arguments, the start point of the path and the end point. A longer path will be drawn and clipped to size to ensure that the straight bits are all in the clippings and not in the remaining fabric of the diagram.

I don't know how the `gluon` relates to the target image, so I left it out, especially since it appeared to want LuaTeX. Obviously, it can be replaced if and where required.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,fadings}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  my snake/.style={decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, post length=0pt}},
  pics/wiggle/.style 2 args={%
    code={%
      \begin{scope}
        \clip ([yshift=.5mm]#1) rectangle  ([yshift=-.5mm]#2);
        \draw [my snake] ([xshift=-2mm]#1) --  ([xshift=2mm]#2);
      \end{scope}%
    },
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,3);
  \draw (0,0) -- (0,3);
  % because the \coordinate ... at ... fails
  \foreach \i [count=\j]  in {(0.9,2.5), (1.1,2.5), (1,1.5), (0,2.5), (2,2.5)} \path \i coordinate (p\j);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (p1) [out=-180, in=180] to (p3) [out=0, in=0] to (p2) [out=-180, in=0] to cycle;
    \begin{scope}[shift=($($(p1)!1/2!(p2)$)!1/2!(p3)$), scale=.25]
      % p. 604
      \foreach \l/\i/\j\k/\m in {(0,0)/2mm/60/1mm/red!50!gray,(-.25,1)/1.9mm/-60/1.5mm/red!25!black,(.5,-1)/2mm/70/2mm/red!20!gray!90!black,(.3,.5)/2mm/60/2mm/red!30!black,(.4,1.15)/2.1mm/80/1mm/red,(-.1,-1)/1.85mm/40/2.5mm/black,(.1,-.7)/2mm/80/2mm/gray}
      {
        \path [opacity=.5, blend mode=overlay, \m, inner color=\m!50, outer color=\m, path fading=circle with fuzzy edge 15 percent, opacity=.6] \l circle (15mm) ;
        \path [decoration={waves, segment length=\i, angle=\j, radius=\k}, line width=.3mm, postaction={decorate, draw}, opacity=.35, blend mode=difference, \m] \l circle (5mm) ;
      }
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
  \pic {wiggle={p4}{p1}};
  \pic {wiggle={p2}{p5}};
  \draw[dashed] (p1)   to[out=-180,in=180]   (p3);
  \draw[dashed] (p2)  to[out=0,in=0] (p3);
  \draw[red] (0.9,3.2) -- +(0,-0.7);
  \draw[red] (1.1,3.2) -- +(0,-0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mixing]

Answer (score 3):

To "scribble" over a region you could choose a suitable path to fill the region and morph it using `coil` or `random steps`:

Coil:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  mixing/.style={decorate, decoration={coil, amplitude=.125cm, segment length=.125cm, aspect=.75}},
  water/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=0mm}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1,1.25) -- +(0,-3) -- +(2,-3) -- +(2,0);
  \draw[water] (-1, .7) -- +(2,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (.5 and .75);
  \draw[double, double distance=.3cm, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,.6); % tube
  \draw [mixing] (0,.5) arc (450:70:.25 and .5);
  \draw [mixing, red] (0,.25) arc (90:540:.13 and .25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coil]

Random steps:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  mixing/.style={decorate, decoration={random steps, amplitude=.25cm, segment length=.2mm}, rounded corners=1mm},
  water/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm,post length=0mm}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1,1.25) -- +(0,-3) -- +(2,-3) -- +(2,0);
  \draw[water] (-1, .7) -- +(2,0);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) circle (.5 and .75);
  \draw[double, double distance=.2cm, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,.6);
  \draw [mixing] (0,0) circle (.25 and .5);
  \draw [mixing, red] (0,0) circle (.2 and .4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: random steps]

The smooth path morphing doesn't work particularly consistently on paths that are already tightly curved, but if you just need a scribble then a few sharp corners probably don't hurt much.

You may of course like to fiddle with the morphing parameters. For some parameters the path morphing gives a `Dimension too large.` error, but it doesn't seem to have any noticeable ramifications.

Results with `random steps` may vary (randomly), so you might want to pick a seed which gives nice results (by using `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`).